# Best way to clean the Apple Mighty Mouse?

Tags: mouse, mighty-mouse

As much as I love Apple products' designs, I still don't like the mighty mouse. The scrolling keeps stopping in between very frequently.

I tried the instructions provided on Apple's site and it does make the scrolling smooth but only momentarily. Isn't there any way to open it up and clean like a normal mouse? Or any other way to clean it better?

Comment: My solution to the Mighty Mouse was to go to Office Max and buy a nice Microsoft mouse for my Mac Mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/214/How+do+I+open+up+a+Mighty+Mouse)?

Comment: Not a bad resource, but be wary of opening up the mouse as you'll probably void any warranty. Rubbing alcohol seems the best approach.

Comment: Yup, I think so too... But if that doesn't work, will just open it up! Thanks Joril

Answer (score 1):

You can open it up and clean it, but there are a couple of points..

1. You need to 'unglue' the ring around the bottom, which then needs gluing back on afterwards. I'm sure the links others have provided mention this. (I just looked on YouTube for a video showing the process when I did it.)
2. Taking the small rollerball apart is quite fiddely. The rollers are very small and all 4 of them come out. Having said that it's all fairly logical in there and obvious where the bits go. Just don't lose them!

Answer (score 0):

Don't disassemble it, period.

Get a clean, lint-free cloth; microfiber cloths work best. Slightly dampen it with water, lay the cloth flat on the desk, turn the mouse upside-down, and run the ball back and forth over the moistened cloth. It may help to hold the mouse at an angle, as though it were a wheelbarrow and the ball was the wheel.

I personally used to use Windex for better effect (but now I use a Magic Mouse and the MagicPrefs prefpane instead of a Mighty Mouse).

http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT3226/HT326.mov

Comment: Have tried this multiple times. It works for a week or so and then again starts giving trouble. Will try the alcohol thing.

Comment: @lost: Specifically use Windex instead of alcohol. It will cut grease better with its ammonia and surfactants.